# Using Tracking with less than three cards

Tags: hearthstone

Does using the card Tracking with less than 3 cards remaining in your deck cause you to take fatigue damage?

[image: Tracking Card]

For instance, if you have 0 cards left in your deck, and use tracking. Do you take 3 rounds of fatigue? Or 0? Because you technically wouldn't draw anything. But you do go through 3 cards.

Context: I was a priest and I Mind Visioned a hunter who was holding a single card, Tracking. He had no cards left in his deck. I assumed he was holding it because he wanted me to think that he had a viable option for 1 more turn OR he didn't want to take more fatigue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It says

> Look at the top tree cards... Draw one...

[image: starting hand]

Having 2 cards left, you would look at the 2 of them and pick which one to draw and discard the other, no fatigue taken.
[image: first played]

Having 1 card left, you would look at that card and draw it, being the lone card left, there's no option for you to choose from. No fatigue taken either (as Studoku confirms in his answer).

Having no card left, you don't take a [fatigue](http://www.blizzposts.com/topic/en/216984/fatigue-clarification) hit, since you can't look up at any cards, you can't draw one, no fatigue.
[image: 0card]

As you can see from the screenshot of my testing, my health haven't changed after playing the second one with no more cards.

Looking at cards doesn't count as drawing them, neither is discarding them considered a draw attempt.

Note that fatigue is represented as a card but it's not a card at all, it's just the way Blizzard decided to represent it. It could have been a stabbing dagger, a chicken biting you or whatever... so don't mistake the look fatigue got with it being anything but a effect of having no more card and **having** to draw one.

Comment: Hearthstone isn't always consistent with rules text though. Have you actually tried this?

Comment: @Studoku, if you want to get technical it's not the drawing that causes Fatigue, it's trying to grab the Fatigue card. If you're just looking at it but don't grab it you shouldn't take any damage (consistent with observations). An interesting question is what happens to the *next* Fatigue draw, is it 1 damage or 4? (1 and 2 being skipped by Tracking).

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau A lot of experience where the wording isn't immediately intuitive. Also the test I did where I didn't have time to test with 0.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau You're the one making a claim- the burden of proof is on you.

Comment: Well I hadn't though that one out correctly, since there's no card to look, there's no draw possible.

Answer (score 3):

Just tried this with a control hunter deck and practice mode.

Using tracking with 1 card in your deck lets you look at it and cause your hero to announce he's out of cards. You are then forced to pick that card, putting it in your hand. You take no fatigue damage.

Comment: And with no card? Since the question specifically state 0 card.

Comment: What happens with 0 cards? Do you draw from nothing or pick from nothing? Two very different things would happen.